# getting error Unexpected value for ''rel_model" Expected "Model", "Proxy", "DeferredRelation", or "self"

Tags: python, peewee, flask-peewee

I have the following class

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    user = peewee.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = peewee.CharField(max_length=256)

class UserRoles(db.Model):
    user = peewee.ForeignKeyField(User, related_name="roles")
```

I have `export FLASK_APP=run.py`
so when I run flask create_user (jsut a test user) from terminalI get the error saying:

```
Unexpected value for "rel_model" Expected "Model", "Proxy", "DeferredRelation", or "self"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting userMixin as the first class -- then db.Model as the second. Multi-inheritance is a bit weird with Python.

Comment: well, that was how it was in the begining and what you are suggesting is what I thought so I tried `UserMixin` followed by `db.Model`